# HTML/JS: How to change option value of select type using JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I've been trying to figure out how to set a value to a an option in a select type. But no matter how much I try to understand I just can't (feels ashamed)..

So I was hoping that you guys could help me since you've helped me so many times before.. :)

Let's say we have:

```
<select name="box" id="test">    
<option value='tval'>Content</option>
```

shouldn't this next code change the text from 'Content' to 'box'?

```
function changeContent(form){
form.document.getElementById('test').options['tval'].value = 'box';
}
```

or am I completely wrong here? I've looked up so many different articles but no one could help me understand how to do this..

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If You need to change the text rather than the value;

```
function changeContent(){
     document.getElementById('test').options[0].text = 'box';
}
```

To set both the value and text;

```
function changeContent(){
     var opt= document.getElementById('test').options[0];
     opt.value =  'box';
     opt.text = 'box';
}
```

Comment: tried this, does not work.. If this is accurate then i'll have to check the other bits of code to see if i made an error.. which i dont think.. this is really tricky when you're new to it.. =)
thanks for answer=)

Comment: @Mr.Havoc it is probably because you are doing `form.document`, try just `document.getEle...`

Comment: Thanks.. the form. was the problem... Why is that?? The JS and HTML are in different files... *confused*

thanks everyone who answered!

Comment: @Mr.Havoc I assume `form` was a DOM element and as such that object wont have access to the `document` variable (`form.document` was probably throwing a Javascript error in your console), that is only present in `window.document` or simply put just `document`.

Comment: ok, thanks, how can i get this error console? Using CODA and Chrome as browser... sorry for noob-question.

Comment: @Mr.Havoc click the spanner next to the address bar, go to Tools > Javascript Console

Answer (score 1):

No, `value` is the actual value of the option element, what will be sent when the user submits the form. What you are trying to access is the HTML of the option element, you would have to access it with something like:

```
form.document.getElementById('test').options['tval'].innerHTML='box'
```

Comment: like i commented before, does not work.. if this is accurate I'll have to check the rest of my code for errors.. thanks alot for answer.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use index of the option here.
Here is the working example http://jsfiddle.net/LaMJ9/

Code

```
document.getElementById('test').options[0].value = 'box';
```

**Edit**

addded alerts for previous and new values at jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LaMJ9/1/

Answer (score 1):

That will change the value from 'tval' to 'box'

I think what you are looking for is the inner text of the option.

W3CSchools.com has an example of what you are looking for in javascript. You did want javascript, correct?

http://w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_option_settext

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `form.` part and use:

```
document.getElementById('test').options[0].innerHTML = 'box';
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hMqFE/