# How I can upload file to parent folder?

Tags: html

Here is the issue

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

If I want to upload file to volvo or audi it is easy. I dont know how I can upload/attach a file to Swedih Car or German Car folder. I cant select parent title( Swedish Car)Is there any jquery plugin out there to solve this isuue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716064/html-js-how-to-change-option-value-of-select-type-using-js

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup  open this link and you will see what i am trying to say. You wont be able to select Swedish cars

Answer (score 0):

Add an *all* option.

```
<optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
  <option value="swedish cars">All Swedish Cars</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</optgroup>
```