# JQuery - Set value and text

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to JQuery and need some help. Although there are few questions based on mine, but could not resolve the issue I have.

I am persisting the entire form as JSON in a table. Upon retrieval, I need to populate multiple dropdowns, mutliselect list box etc. The JSON retrieved looks like this.

```
"{"dateType":"TODAY","quickSetDate":"ANOTHER_DATE"}"
```

Note: dateType is the id in form and stored as key in JSON.

What the form looks like.

```
<select id="dateType" class="form-control selectpicker" name="dateType">
    <option value="today">Today</option>
    <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
    <option value="date_after">Day After</option>
</select>
```

Dropdown id's are `dateType` and `quickSetDate`. What I need to do is, based on JSON value (TODAY), I need to search in the dropdown, set that value and change the text to "Today".

Any help would be appreciated.

Jquery version is 2.x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/JS: How to change option value of select type using JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716064/html-js-how-to-change-option-value-of-select-type-using-js)

Comment: _"What I need to do is, based on JSON value (TODAY), I need to search in the dropdown, set that value and change the text to "Today""_ The value and  text appear to already be set to "today", "Today" , respectively ?

Comment: Probably it is. Thanks. But not the solution I am looking for. When I retrieve the JSON, I do not have the text to be set. This has to happen based on the value I have in hand. For eg. "TODAY", "TOMORROW" or "DAY_AFTER"

Comment: you can set the text with your JSON data. instead of a string in the text = method, put a variable that has the JSON data in it.

Comment: @guest271314 - By default yes. If the JSON value was anything other than "today", "Today", it should it set accordingly. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: @SamanthRao Only the first `option` should be set to property value ? And `option` should be selected ?

Comment: @guest271314. That is right.

Comment: @SamanthRao See post

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON data for dateType comes back in the variable data, you'd try something like:

```
$('#dateType').options[0].text(data.dateType);
```

for setting the value too, change .text() to val();

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to select directly the option with the value in the json. try this

```
var json = {"dateType":"tomorrow","quickSetDate":"ANOTHER_DATE"};
var jsonValue = json.dateType;

// loop on each option
$('#dateType option').each(function(index,currentOption){
        var currentValue = $(currentOption).val();// value of current option
        if(currentValue.localeCompare(jsonValue) == 0){
            // if value are the same select this option
            $(currentOption).prop('selected', true);
            return false;// stop loop
        }
});
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse()` , `for..in` loop , `.is()` , `.prepend()` , `String.prototype.charAt()`, `String.prototype.slice()` , `String.prototype.toLowerCase()`

```js
var data = '{"dateType":"TODAY","quickSetDate":"ANOTHER_DATE"}';

var obj = JSON.parse(data);

for (var prop in obj) {
  if ($("select").is("#" + prop)) {
    $("#" + prop)
    .prepend($("<option>", {
      val: obj[prop].toLowerCase(),
      html: obj[prop].charAt(0) + obj[prop].slice(1).toLowerCase(),
      selected: true
    }))    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="dateType" class="form-control selectpicker" name="dateType">
</select>
```